# How to sort a collection to get the default value at top/bottom in java?

Tags: java

Given a list of String sometimes we had to sort all items except for few items which either have to be put on top or at the bottom,

```
List<String> profiles = Arrays.asList(new String[] {
        "Y-Profile", "X-Profile", "Default", "A-Profile", "B-Profile"
    });

List<String> sortedProfiles = profiles.stream().sorted((o1, o2)->o1.compareTo(o2)).
                                   collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Current output with default comparison of string is as below,

```
sortedProfiles ==> [A-Profile, B-Profile, Default, X-Profile, Y-Profile]
```

The required output is as below, what is the optimistic way to do it in java without much iteration or filtering as the list size is dynamic and could become large over a period of time

```
sortedProfiles ==> [Default, A-Profile, B-Profile, X-Profile, Y-Profile]
```

Comment: try to implement your own comparator

Comment: Remove the items, sort, insert the items?

Comment: Removing is an option, but removing requires one more iteration, is there a way to do it without one more iteration ?

Comment: `String`s get sorted in natural order (that is alphabetical order, most likely). You will have to write your own `Comparator` for an order which always starts with `"Default"`. You could call it `"00-Default"`...

Comment: Yes, as dehasi says: write your own comparator that knows that the String "Default" needs to be treated differently than your other custom strings. You are not sorting, you are applying a very special *different* ordering scheme for strings!

Comment: Sorting takes `O(n log n)` time, removing/inserting - `O(n)`. These 2 iterations cost nothing for large arrays. It also will be faster than custom comparator, since you don't need to perform default-element-checks at each comparison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement a more intelligent comparator than simply `o1.compareTo(o2)`. You may end up with something like this (not necessarily the most efficient though):

```
final String defaultVal = "Default";
List<String> sortedProfiles = profiles.stream().sorted(
    (o1, o2) -> defaultVal.equals(o1) && defaultVal.equals(o2)
                ? 0
                : (defaultVal .equals(o1)
                   ? -1
                   : (defaultVal .equals(o2) ? 1 : o1.compareTo(o2)))
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: In case you have two default values `v1` and `v2` it will be problem: `v1` < `v2` and `v2` < `v1`. Also default value less than itself.

Comment: @talex It's trivial to add additional check for them both being default.  I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by removing the value `"Default"` before sorting and adding it to the output list before you add the sorted ones:

```
public class StackoverflowMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> profiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        profiles.add("Y-Profile");
        profiles.add("Z-Profile");
        profiles.add("U-Profile");
        profiles.add("A-Profile");
        profiles.add("Default");
        profiles.add("G-Profile");
        profiles.add("B-Profile");
        // print the list once for comparison in the console
        System.out.println(profiles);

        // create a new list that is supposed to hold the sorted values
        List<String> sortedProfiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        // remove the value that will not be sorted "correctly"
        profiles.remove("Default");
        // add it as the first element to the list for the sorted values
        sortedProfiles.add("Default");
        // then add the naturally sorted origin (which has no "Default" anymore)
        sortedProfiles.addAll(profiles.stream()
                .sorted((termOne, termTwo) -> termOne.compareTo(termTwo))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        // print the manipulated / sorted list for comparison in the console
        System.out.println(sortedProfiles);
    }
}
```

If you aren't sure there is a `"Default"` in the profiles list, then add a `contains("Default")` check and just do a regular sorting if it isn't there.

Answer (score 1):

Take the items which you don't want to sort in another List.(might be more than one).

```
List<String> profiles = Arrays
            .asList(new String[] { "Y-Profile", "X-Profile", "Default", "A-Profile", "B-Profile}" });

    List<String> itemsToIgnore = Stream.of("Default").collect(Collectors.toList());
```

sort the list while ignore the items in ignoreList.
concat the sorted and ignoreStream in the preferred order

```
    List<String> defaultAtTop = Stream
            .concat(itemsToIgnore.stream(), profiles.stream().filter(s -> !itemsToIgnore.contains(s)).sorted())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(defaultAtTop);

    List<String> defaultAtBottom = Stream
            .concat(profiles.stream().filter(s -> !itemsToIgnore.contains(s)).sorted(), itemsToIgnore.stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(defaultAtBottom);
```

Comment: Why on earth would you explicitly wrap the varargs parameters to `Arrays.asList` in an array?

Comment: I don't. It was the way OP wants it.

Answer (score 1):

I like @Aleks G's answer and want to give a similar answer using BiFunction, as i am somehow learning/expermenting the functional interface myself. Please test before use as I am not very experienced and cann't guarantee that this will work in any case.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> profiles = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"Y-Profile", "X-Profile", "Default", "A-Profile", "B-Profile"});

    BiFunction<String,String,Integer> fun = (a,b)->{ return a.equals("Default")?-1:
                                                            b.equals("Default")? 1:
                                                            a.compareTo(b);};
    List<String> sortedProfiles = profiles.stream()
                                 .sorted((s1,s2)->fun.apply(s1, s2))
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(sortedProfiles);
}
```